# How to highlight feature on Click in Mapbox Gl JS Vector Layer like in 2nd Image

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

How to highlight a feature in the layer. 1st image shows the layer and 2nd image is the selected feature highlighted on click.How to do this ?

[Vector Layer in Mapbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0mq5.jpg)

[Selected Feature Highlighted Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiSTP.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the Vector Layer screenshot you've linked to has polygon data and isn't just a Raster Layer, you can use [Feature State](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfeaturestate) to accomplish this. Here's an example of using feature state to modify styling at runtime on the client: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/

For your purposes, rather than using the `"mousemove"` & `"mouseleave"` events that the above example uses, you can use the [`"click"`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#on) event to trigger your polygon's style change.

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work for Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: Yes tried updating the feature state using setFeatureState function but if you look closely in the 2nd image that I have shared, the intensity of base layer of map also gets changed on click on any polygon. How to achieve that ?

Comment: It's hard to advise you on the best course of action without an idea of what your data/implementation look like. Can you share an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this issue can help?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326243/mapbox-gl-feature-manipulation/326394#326394

You have to alter the color properties and reset the source

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. We can use background layer with dark color and use an additional layer of the same polygon to resemble that effect by increasing background opacity of the background layer.